# Getting 404 when i refresh the page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, vite

I get 404 whenever refresh the page it works for the first time but when I refresh I get 404. It is a React + TypeScript + Vite web application deployed on the Azure app service

[image]

Comment: How you are deploying the WebApp ?

Comment: Yes On azure app service

Comment: From VS Code or Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Got the fix we have to create a file in `/public` which is `staticwebapp.config.json`

And the File will contain.

```
    {
    "navigationFallback": {
      "rewrite": "/index.html",
      "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
    }
  }
```